# How do I “Hack in” an Accessibility Option to Android 4.4.3?

Tags: android, root

Much like the invert colors option in settings, what are the first resources I need to could "Hack" android and add in my own setting that could apply a visual transformation to the screen? (i.e., fish eye effect, turn screen upside down, etc).

Comment: That is basically, creating custom rom. You cant just "hack in". I suspect your question will be closed soon.

Comment: There's quite a lot of apps which do things like this - eg. the broken screen pranks. see [here](http://www.piwai.info/chatheads-basics/) for how it's basically done - it's the "Draw over other apps" permission which lets an app do this.